# errorTip on Flex ComboBox

Tags: apache-flex

I have a tooltip on a ComboBox but I much prefer the styling of the errorTip
(with the "tail").

I have replaced the tooltip with an errorTip, but now the ComboBox has a red
border.

I'm still pretty much a newb... is there a way to override the red border on the
ComboBox so that its' border is back to good ol' black?

thanks,

Mark

Comment: share some code, is this flex 3 or 4?

Comment: Have you had a chance to try the answer I posted? If it helped solve your problem, you can upvote it by clicking on the ^ arrow and you can mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check mark icon next to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You'd probably want to create your own custom tooltip as errorTip is reserved for the validation system.

There's some info [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf60d65-7ff6.html) about how to create your own.  It's fairly straightforward if you want something simple.

Comment: jax - the problem I'm having is not with the errorTip itself - it's with the red border of the ComboBox...

Comment: ...still, I take your point... I'm hoping to learn how to override the ComboBox Border to show black.

Comment: are you setting the 'errorString' property?  Either that or have a validator attached to the combobox that's failing.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something I've used in the past:

**The Actionscript:**

```
private var infoToolTip:ToolTip;
private function showToolTip(evt:MouseEvent, text:String):void
{
  var pt:Point = new Point(evt.currentTarget.x, evt.currentTarget.y);

  // Convert the targets 'local' coordinates to 'global' -- this fixes the
  // tooltips positioning within containers.
  pt = evt.currentTarget.parent.contentToGlobal(pt);

  infoToolTip = ToolTipManager.createToolTip(text, pt.x, pt.y, "errorTipAbove") as ToolTip;
  infoToolTip.setStyle("borderColor", "#87B846");
  infoToolTip.setStyle("color", "white");
  var yOffset:int =  infoToolTip.height + 5;
  infoToolTip.y -= yOffset;
  infoToolTip.x -= 5
}

// Remove the tooltip
private function killToolTip():void
{
  ToolTipManager.destroyToolTip(infoToolTip);
}
```

**Using the toolTip:**

```
<mx:Image source="{myImageSource}" mouseOver="showToolTip(event, 'Hello there!')" mouseOut="killToolTip()" />
```